# In scrapy is there a way to obtain the complete text from a div?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am working with scrapy in order to crawl the content from certain sections of the webpage. I need the text to be scraped exactly as displayed in the webpage. The webpage is structured similar to this.

```
<div class = "uselessInfo">...</div>
<div class = "usefulInfo">
       Some text
       <p>Useful paragraph</p>
       <p>Useful paragraph with <a><span>Important Keywords</span></a>
       <ul>Some interesting data</ul>
</div>
<div class = "usefulInfo">
       Some text
       <ul>Some interesting data</ul>
       <p>Useful paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class = "uselessInfo">...</div>
```

When I extract the info I cannot access the text from the child elements. And this also happens in case of the keywords inside the paragraphs.

Is there any way to obtain the text from the parent element (usefulInfo in the example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `*` like this

```
your_text = "".join(response.css(".uselessInfo *::text").getall())
```